# Перебрать все возможные варианты расставления строчек

Tags: python, строки

Всем доброго дня.
Если возможность, помогите со скриптом форматирования строки.

> Нужно расставлять точки между буквами в строке. Допустим у нас есть
> строка "string" Нужно создать список строк в формате:
>
> 1. "strin.g"
> 2. "stri.ng"
> 3. "stri.n.g"
> 4. "str.ing"
> 5. "str.i.ng"
>
> Т.е. перебрать все возможные варианты расставления точек. Точки
> предположительно будут расположены как при увеличении битового
> числа...
>
> 1. "0001"
> 2. "0010"
> 3. "0011"
> 4. "0100"
> 5. "0110"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def insdot(s):
    def w(s):
        if len(s) == 1:
            return [s]
        else:
            return map(lambda x: s[0]+x, w(s[1:])) + map(lambda x: s[0]+'.'+x, w(s[1:]))
    return w(s)[1:]
```

**Добавлено:**
А вот предложенное решение с отображением целых.

```
def insdot(s):
    p = 1 << (len(s)-1)
    l = []
    for i in range(1, p):
        def rf(first, sec):
            c = first[0]
            s1 = sec
            if c & i > 0 :
                s1 = '.'+s1
            return (c >> 1, first[1]+s1)
        l.append(reduce(rf, s[1:], (p >> 1, s[0]))[1])
    return l
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Добавил вариант решения из вопроса.

Answer (score 6):

Решение одной строчкой:

```
from itertools import product
word = 'string'

['%s'.join(word) % x for x in product(('', '.'), repeat=len(word)-1)]

# ['string', 'strin.g', 'stri.ng', 'stri.n.g', 'str.ing', 'str.in.g', 'str.i.ng', 'str.i.n.g', 'st.ring', 'st.rin.g', 'st.ri.ng', 'st.ri.n.g', 'st.r.ing', 'st.r.in.g', 'st.r.i.ng', 'st.r.i.n.g', 's.tring', 's.trin.g', 's.tri.ng', 's.tri.n.g', 's.tr.ing', 's.tr.in.g', 's.tr.i.ng', 's.tr.i.n.g', 's.t.ring', 's.t.rin.g', 's.t.ri.ng', 's.t.ri.n.g', 's.t.r.ing', 's.t.r.in.g', 's.t.r.i.ng', 's.t.r.i.n.g']
```

Вот за это я и люблю питон :)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с одним [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools


def dots(s):
    iters = []
    for c in s[:-1]:
        iters.extend(((c, ), ('', '.')))
    iters.append((s[-1], ))
    return map(''.join, itertools.product(*iters))


print(*dots(input()), sep='\n')
```

> ```
> $ echo string | python dots.py
> string
> strin.g
> stri.ng
> stri.n.g
> str.ing
> str.in.g
> str.i.ng
> str.i.n.g
> st.ring
> st.rin.g
> st.ri.ng
> st.ri.n.g
> st.r.ing
> st.r.in.g
> st.r.i.ng
> st.r.i.n.g
> s.tring
> s.trin.g
> s.tri.ng
> s.tri.n.g
> s.tr.ing
> s.tr.in.g
> s.tr.i.ng
> s.tr.i.n.g
> s.t.ring
> s.t.rin.g
> s.t.ri.ng
> s.t.ri.n.g
> s.t.r.ing
> s.t.r.in.g
> s.t.r.i.ng
> s.t.r.i.n.g
> ```